# Music play only one time

Tags: android, button, audio

I'm trying to play sound on Button's `setOnClickListener`. this is what i'm trying:

```
final MediaPlayer mpclikc = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.click);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View var1) {
                mpclikc.start();
            }
        });
```

The problem is sound play only once!

Sound play only the first time I click on Button!! What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you want it to act when you press the button again. Do you want it to play from the the current position? Or do you want to reset it?

However I would just read through the API doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

mpclikc.reset();
mpclikc.play();